# json.serializeArray, not including arrayed elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization

I am getting a really wired issue while using the `serializeArray` on form submit via ajax.

Here is any example of my code:

```js
console.log($('form').serializeArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="..." method="post">
  <input type="text" name="title" value="input value">

  <select name="select_one" id="select_one">
    <option value="1">Select 1 - 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Select 1 - 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select 1 - 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="select_two[]" id="select_two[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>Select 2 - 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Select 2 - 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select 2 - 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="select_three[]" id="select_three[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>Select 3 - 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Select 3 - 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select 3 - 3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="mobile" value="1234567890">
</form>
```

Output

```js
{
    "title": "input value",
    "select_one": 2,
    "mobile": 1234567890
}
```

Whereas it should have been

```js
{
    "title": "input value",
    "select_one": 2,
    "select_two": [1, 2],
    "select_three": [1, 2],
    "mobile": 1234567890
}
```

All the elements except the arrayed ones are collected.

I have tried googling this issue but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output shown in the question is your goal, then `serializeArray()` is not the correct method to achieve it. That returns an array of objects with each object containing one value per field. It doesn't return not a single object containing string/array values as your goal requires.

To do what you need you will have to build the object manually:

```js
$('form').on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const output = {};
  $(e.target).find(':input[name]').each((i, el) => output[el.name] = $(el).val());
  
  console.log(output);
  
  // ajax request here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="..." method="post">
  <input type="text" name="title" value="input value">

  <select name="select_one" id="select_one">
    <option value="1">Select 1 - 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Select 1 - 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select 1 - 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="select_two[]" id="select_two[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>Select 2 - 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Select 2 - 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select 2 - 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="select_three[]" id="select_three[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>Select 3 - 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Select 3 - 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select 3 - 3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="mobile" value="1234567890">
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```